# Insert data to existing record

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

how can i insert and replace data in table to existing row from java, depends on ID?
I want to give statement like that

```
insert into rooms(status) values('occupied')
  where id_room = 5;
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, because it would require a ton of code to show you how to setup a JDBC connection and do the `INSERT`.  Try using a tutorial like MKYong, and if you get stuck come back here with a more focused question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `update` statement instead of `insert`.

Like that:

```
Update rooms set status = 'accupied' where Id = 5
```

So now the table will update the data with the new values.